# how to use input values in it's own files in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to take the input value which is its city name. Then add URL (this.cityNameSearch) strings. but it does not work. How do I use input values on its file?

**posts.component.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css']
})
export class PostsComponent {


  @Input() cityNameSearch:string;


  apikey:string = 'f2b412c0e169b2dbc28e13691fc4566b'
  url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=' + this.cityNameSearch+ '&appid='+this.apikey;

  posts;
  ngOnInit() {
    
    
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    
    http.get(this.url).subscribe(response => {
      this.posts = response;
      console.log(this.posts)
      console.log(this._categoryId)
      })
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  cityname:string;

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.cityname);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form (submit) = "onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" name="cityname" placeholder="City Name" [(ngModel)]="cityname">
  <i class="fas fa-search-location"></i>
</form>
<app-posts [cityNameSearch]="cityname"></app-posts>
```

Comment: try using this `<app-posts [cityNameSearch]={{cityname}}></app-posts>`

Comment: it gave error (emplate parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{cityname}}] in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using *ngIf on app-post to trigger the component,

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <input
    type="text"
    name="cityname"
    placeholder="City Name"
    [(ngModel)]="cityname"
  />
  <i class="fas fa-search-location"></i>
</form>
<button (click)="onclear()">clear</button>

<app-post *ngIf="hidden" [cityNameSearch]="cityname"></app-post>
```

here is the sample [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wta3lf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)